# Can I hook into the component creation part of the Angular Router?

Tags: angular

Motivation: I want to add a directive to the component created for a specific route. This would be really neat, since I could then describe some important information declaratively.

I've checked and read that directives can't be added to programmatically created components. I... find that hard to accept. But surely the information for doing so must be present at least at the point the Router creates the component, right?

Comment: What about using `attributes` of the routes instead? You can set them in the `routes` file and read them in the component to interpret the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can extend the default `RouterOutlet` directive and overwrite some of its behaviors (or implement the same logic from scratch) and then use something like `<my-router-outlet>` in the markup. but in case of routing the components are created dynamically. As I know there is no way to assign directive to a dynamically created component, but you could send something inside via the `injector`, component properties(`@Input()`s) or even via the `projectableNodes`. But you should really think about it carefully, because most probably this data can be sent via the Route -> `data` property, and then be read inside of the component